# mysql query with array as WHERE parameter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

there is an email address in the user session, and I am trying to use the extracted info to access the other relevant info on the user from the database. Here is what I have.

```
$author = explode(":", $_SESSION['user_id']);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `active`='1' AND `email`=$author[1]");

while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

// does stuff in here.

}
```

for some reason I get back "mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given."
If I echo out "$author['1']" I get the correct email address for the logged in user. How do I go
about writing the query correctly?

Comment: need to put single quotes arroud this in `$author['1']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put:

> "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `active`='1' AND `email`=**'".$author[1]."'**"

make sure you have propper quotes up there

Answer (score 0):

```
$qry ="SELECT * FROM users WHERE `active`='1' AND `email`= ".$author['1'];
$query = mysql_query($qry);
```

Comment: An explanation of what you are doing differently and why would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `active`='1' AND `email`='".$author[1]."'");
```

Comment: An explanation of what you are doing differently and why would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose variable in quotes with curly brackets:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `active`='1' AND `email`={$author[1]}");
```

Although I have one more tip:
run queries like this : 
    $query = mysql_query('...') or die(mysql_error());
With this you will at least know why it fails.

P.S. I guess you have a reason to use mysql extension, but anyway you should use PDO or mysqli over mysql. You get placeholders with mysqli, or named parameters with PDO. Much nicer to work with.